# r weighting a matrix

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, weighted

I have a nx5 matrix. The first 6 rows as follows

```
  x1    x2   x3  x4  x5
   1    30    3  43   0
   3    40    2  35   0
   3    50    7  72   0
   4    40   58  63  10
   1    20   19  61  10
   4    20    5  49   0
```

Also I have column of nx1 matrix which represents the weights.

```
 w
 1.080042
 1.083287
 1.141108
 1.191246
 1.117395
 1.081123
```

My goal is to weight the initial nx5 matrix with these weights. I tried 
`a%*%w` but this resulted in a 5x1 matrix. This is not what I want. My question is how do i generate a weighted nx5 matrix ? Thanks.

Comment: can you show the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to multiply the values of the first dataset rows with the corresponding values of second dataset

```
df1 * df2[row(df1)]
```

Or with `matrix`es

```
m1 * m2[row(m1)]
```

---

or using `sweep`

```
sweep(df1, 1, df2$w, `*`)
sweep(m1, 1, m2[,1], `*`)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L), x2 = c(30L, 40L, 
50L, 40L, 20L, 20L), x3 = c(3L, 2L, 7L, 58L, 19L, 5L), x4 = c(43L, 
35L, 72L, 63L, 61L, 49L), x5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(w = c(1.080042, 1.083287, 1.141108, 1.191246, 
1.117395, 1.081123)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

m1 <- as.matrix(df1)
m2 <- as.matrix(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, how do we do this when the two objects are matrix and not a dataframe ?

Comment: @SaraU If it is matirx, `m1 * m2[row(m1)]` where `m1 <- as.matrix(df1); m2 <- as.matrix(df2)`  In the second optoin, replace the `df2$w` with `m2[,1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply multiplying each column by the vector then just

```
mt * vc
```

Where `mt` is (the name of) your matrix and `vc` is (the name of) your vector, for example taking

```
mt <- (diag(5)+0.1)
vc <- c(1:5)
mt * vc
```

Gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
[2,]  0.2  2.2  0.2  0.2  0.2
[3,]  0.3  0.3  3.3  0.3  0.3
[4,]  0.4  0.4  0.4  4.4  0.4
[5,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  5.5
```

If your weights are in a one column matrix then convert then to a vector first with `as.vector()`

Comment: bingo converting my weights to vectors did the trick. Thanks rg255